# Dell Studio 1749 AC Adapter Cut Out

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, dell-studio

**The problem**

I have a Dell Studio 1749 laptop, well outside of warranty (unfortunately) that developed a strange problem. Basically, the power adapter cuts out when you plug it in while the computer is running.

If you plug the adapter in while the computer is not running, and the battery is in or out (and either fully charged or not) it will be fine. Turning it on also works and the adapter remains on, again regardless of battery occupation or condition.

The net effect is I am immobile unless I want to shut my laptop down. I haven't do so recently, but I think putting the laptop to sleep also doesn't help (in order to not have too much power usage from the hardware).

**Backstory**

I have replaced the power button, added a secondary HDD, upgraded the Wi-Fi card and added more RAM - all fine, didn't cause this issue (at least initially when they were all done). I can't remember when this issue started, I've had it for a while and since moved back onto a desktop so decommissioned the laptop until recently.

**Initial observations**

It appears at a glance to be a current spike causing the adapter to cut out (safety feature). The only way to bring the adapter back to life is to unplug it from the wall.

This is indicated by the blue LED ring on the adapter plug fading out and not lighting up again until I unplug from mains and plug in again.

**What I have tried**

I have another battery and adapter and have tried all combinations of the four - the results remain the same, so I'm confident there is an issue on one of the power delivery circuits in the laptop itself.

I have tried a complete barebones power up, disconnecting: all HDDs, Wi-Fi card, RAM, keyboard, DVD drive, and monitor. Haven't done that recently, but I remember it made no difference.

I have the service manual and can't see a separate power circuit other than the power button board bit. I have bought a second hand motherboard and it had the same issue (which isn't conclusive, but the chances aren't great that it had the same issue as it was advertised as not).

**Questions (updated)**

- <strike>*What are my options?*</strike>
- <strike>*What other diagnosis approaches do I have available?*</strike>
- *Suspecting the motherboard causing a current spike, what options to I have in diagnosing what the current draw is when the power adapter is plugged into the laptop?*
- *Has anyone else experienced this problem? If so, what was the resolution?*

**Pending activities**

30/09/2015 <strike>Going to try a power supply with a higher rating, fortunately I have access to multiple higher-rated official Dell power supplies. I'll give this a go tonight and report back.</strike>
I got a power supply rated at 130W instead of 90W, outputting 2.5A more than my usual power supply. Still cuts out... :-(

30/09/2015 <strike>Going to take it apart and do a barebones power up again with the new power adapter. Also going to do a visual inspection to see if there are any burn marks or duff contacts.</strike> Visually everything looks ok, and I can narrow the problem down to either the motherboard (hopefully not) and the internal AC power cable and socket. I had a spare one of those knocking around from when I was buying other parts, just got to find it :-/

I suspect the motherboard. There is, cause unknown, a spike in the current requested when the AC adapter is plugged in and it tries to supply power to the board and also the charging circuit on the battery. I believe the DC power jack is fine because it works in all other circumstances.

With it being the motherboard, unless I can fetch one exceedingly cheap, this problem will have to remain :-(

Comment: Plug adapter in wall first then to pc? Check to be sure dc socket on laptop is not damaged.

Comment: @Moab  PC first then wall or wall then PC makes no difference, the only working difference comes from whether the PC is running or not.

Comment: I wonder if you tried an adapter with a higher amperage output.

Comment: @Moab No, I don't have one available, but it does sound like it would address the problem. Initially I'd be hesitant to try that because of risking damage to my laptop further. I may be able to borrow one from work, we use Dell here.

Comment: @Moab Yep, got one rated higher for workstation laptops, I'll give this a brief go tonight and fingers crossed I don't break it any further.

Comment: Good luck, it might be time for a new laptop.

Comment: @Moab Yeah indeed, but this is irritatingly close to being a workable laptop that I'd be remiss not to try and fix it.

Comment: Let us know how it goes, it looks like you have covered all the bases.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you need to check with the 100% working power supply first.

But it looks like it's a motherboard issue. Looks like the some of the charging DC circuits are damaged. At the moment of AC adapter is plugged in, some consumer on the motherboard starts consuming extra current that is over limit that leads to the overcurrent protection detection in the AC and it goes to the protected mode.

In most of the cases, the chip that consumes extra power is overheating, you can find it by touching it with a finger - it will be hot, especially if it is in short circuit.

In many cases in can be a small damaged capacitor that is standing in the input or charging circuits. It causes lower resistance and, in turn, higher current consumption.

To detect such element you need an external laboratory DC power supply. You need to connect red pin to the + of the input power circuits and the black one to the ground. Voltage should be about 19 V. You need to set current on the laboratory power supply 1 A first and increase it to 2.5 A gradually and touch elements on the motherboard in power circuits. At this current the faulty element would start to heat seriously.
This is the basic method used in the service centers to detect short circuits in the power schemes.

The normal resistance in the +19 V input circuits should be tens of kOhms.

Here is the schematic diagram http://zeto.com.ua/web/uploads/shema/file_137.pdf
Page 46 shows Vin and Battery charge circuits. The next pages show the generation of other voltages like 1.5V, 1.25, +5VALWP, etc.
Usually the issue is some of the capacitors that stand near PQ transistor switches.

If you are not familiar with electronics and MB schematics please bring the motherboard to the service center.

Comment: Yeah I'm not familiar with it to that level! To be honest I'm going to leave it as is, the cost of repair does not match the value of the hardware any more. Thanks for the very detailed reply though, hopefully it can help the next person.

Comment: Yeah I have tried it with two batteries and three power supplies, same issue.